# FileHelpers DelimiterFieldBuilder issue

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have this simple file.

```
first name 1,last name 1
first name 2
first name 3,last name 3
first name 4,last name 4
```

- Case 1: I read data from the file using this class:

  ```
      [DelimitedRecord(",")]
      public partial class Person
      {
          private string firstName;

          [FieldNullValue("default last name")]
          private string lastName;

          public string FirstName
          {
              get { return firstName; }
              set { firstName = value; }
          }

          public string LastName
          {
              get { return lastName; }
              set { lastName = value; }
          }
      }
  ```

  and this code

  ```
          ExcelStorage provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(Person));
          provider.FileName = "data.csv";
          Person[] res = provider.ExtractRecords() as Person[];
  ```

I get the data correctly , the second element in the array has the last name = default last name.

- Case 2: I read the data using a dynamically build type:

  ```
          DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("Person2", ",");
          cb.AddField("firstName", typeof(string));
          cb.AddField("lastName", typeof(string));
          cb.LastField.FieldNullValue = "default last name";
          DelimitedFileEngine engine = new DelimitedFileEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());
          DataTable dt = engine.ReadFileAsDT("data.csv");
  ```

I get the following exception : `Line: 2 Column: 0. Delimiter ',' not found after field 'firstName' (the record has less fields, the delimiter is wrong or the next field must be marked as optional).`

Let's change the file like this, adding separator on the second line

```
first name 1,last name 1
first name 2,
first name 3,last name 3
first name 4,last name 4
```

- Case 1 : Reading using the static typed class:
  I get the same result: there is a default last name
- Case 2: Reading using the dynamically created object:
  It doesn't brake anymore but there is no default value, there is just ""

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should set the second field to be optional.

```
  cb.LastField.FieldNullValue = "default last name";
```

Then you don't need to add a comma.

Secondly, if you DO add a comma, then you need to change the way the dynamic runtime class handles empty fields. The `ClassBuilder` is not treating `string.Empty` as `null` (which is probably a bug since it a differs from your first approach where you were not creating the class dynamically). But you can provide a simple converter to handle this.

```
  cb.LastField.Converter.TypeName = typeof(NullValueConverter).ToString();
```

and here is the code for the converter

```
public class NullValueConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string stringSource)
    {
        return stringSource;
    }

    public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
    {
        // treat string.empty as null
        string result = fieldValue.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
            return null;
        return result;
    }
}
```